# How does PHP handle simultaneous hits with same variable names on 1 file

Tags: php, twitter, server, request, ram

I have a php file where I have API code going on. This file is making use of the twitter api, in the file I'm passing user keys via sessions for processing and sending of tweet.

I'm wondering, what would happen when multiple requests are coming to this file at the same second?

If 5 requests from different geographical locations are coming to the file..each with different variable values...but all will be taking the same variable names...does php create 5 instances of that file to perform the tweets?

Please see my code to see what's going on: http://pastebin.com/ic6pYLgi

What would happen when multiple people are sending requests to that file?

```
<?php
session_start();
//pass session variables into  standard variable
$ck = $_SESSION['consumer_key'];
$cs = $_SESSION['consumer_secret'];
$at = $_SESSION['access_token'];
$ats = $_SESSION['access_token_secret'];
$hashtag = $_SESSION['hashtag'];
$tweet = $_POST['tweet'];

//TODO unset session at end of script
//TODO limit tweet length

if (!empty($ck && $cs && $at && $ats && $tweet)){
  $ck = $_POST['consumer_key'] = $ck; //get session value into POST then pass back to variable
  $cs = $_POST['consumer_secret'] = $cs;
  $at = $_POST['access_token'] = $at;
  $ats = $_POST['access_token_secret'] = $ats;
  $_POST['tweet'];
  $hashtag = $_POST['hashtag'] = $hashtag;
}


require "autoload.php";

use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

define('CONSUMER_KEY', $ck); // add app consumer key between single quotes
define('CONSUMER_SECRET', $cs); // add app consumer secret key between single quotes
$access_token = $at;
$access_token_secret = $ats;

$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token, $access_token_secret);

if (!empty($ck && $cs && $at && $ats && $tweet && $hashtag)) {

  $hashtag = '#' . $hashtag;
  $connection->post('statuses/update',array('status' => $tweet . ' ' . $hashtag));
  $t = $connection;
  echo '<pre>';
  //print_r($t);
  echo '</pre>';
  echo "Your message has been sent to Twitter with a hashtag.";
}

//TODO Add error handling to send to special inbox


//Tweet without hashtags

if (!empty($ck && $cs && $at && $ats && $tweet) && empty($hashtag)) {
  $connection->post('statuses/update',array('status' => $tweet));
  //$t = $connection;
  //echo '<pre>';
  //print_r($t);
  //echo '</pre>';
  //echo "Your message has been sent to Twitter without a hashtag.";
}

session_destroy(); //this will hopefully help with load on this file
?>
```

Comment: "does php create 5 instances of that file" =yes.

Comment: @Dagon did you check out the code? If what you are saying is true then i'm golden.

Comment: what happens when people vist the same web page at once - same thing

Comment: The use of session_destroy() is suspicious and might not be doing what you think it is doing.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

Answer (score 0):

Any variables in a php request are independent of any simultaneous requests, so some other request being processed will in no way be making edits to your variables.

The $_SESSION var will contain a copy of the shared session scope.  The copy is made once at the time session_start() is called, and even if there are other simultaneous pages being processed, they will not make any difference to the contents of your $_SESSION

You may not have simultaneous processing going on though.  It is my understanding that PHP cannot process more simultaneous pages than there are processors on the server.  If you have a single processor server, there is no simultaneous processing of pages, a page request that comes in while another one is processing waits in line.

Comment: It's fine if it waits, I just don't want a situation where the variables are overwritten and only that last request by the millisecond gets processed